# making sense of admin-ajax

Tags: custom-field, ajax

So I'm working with ThemeTrust's "reveal" theme, and there is an ajaxed in chunk-of-content that I'm really trying to change (grab custom meta fields (images) + insert into a slideshow).  As far as I can tell the following piece of code grabs the content from the normal tinymce box and drops it in the `#projectHolder` div - but I can't figure out how to piggyback my php code on this request.

```
function loadProject(projectSlug) { 
// Scroll to the top of the projects    
jQuery("#projectHolder").load(      
    MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    {           
        action : 'myajax-submit',           
        slug : projectSlug
    },
    function( response ) {   
    }
);
}
```

I suppose my answer lies somewhere in the 1500+ lines of `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` but that seems awful daunting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that returns the contents of that ajax request will not be in admin-ajax.php. That is the core WordPress file that handles ajax requests, but it is not used for specifying the data returned by ajax functions in themes / plugins.

In the theme (somewhere), will be a line that looks like this:

`add_action('wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'some_function_name_here');`

The function called "some_function_name_here" (which will be named something different than some_function_name_here, as this is just an example) is what determines the data returned to jQuery.

Do a search in the theme files for "add_action('wp_ajax_myajax-submit'" and you should be able to find it.

If you don't find it with that search, then look for

"add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_myajax-submit'"

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!  I think I had it almost figured out after tracing the code a bit and reading http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/.. but you undoubtedly just saved me a fair amount of work.